# Missing padding on moderator vote buttons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The below image illustrates the problem clearly:

[image: Sample image]

There is no padding to the left of the voting buttons, while all other elements on the site are padded from both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed. Here's how it looks now:

[image: screenshot of problem]